# Plain image in Windows Forms StatusStrip control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, controls

I'm trying to put a plain image on a `System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip` control (Visual Studio 2008, C# .Net 3.5).

I remember being able to do it quite easily in earlier framework versions, but for some reason the only controls made available to me from this new StatusStrip are a `StatusLabel`, a `ProgressBar`, a `DropDownButton`, and a `SplitButton`.

I'm using the `SplitButton` control at the moment as it lets me include an image, but it's obviously not ideal as it has the menu dropdown attached to it.

Is there a way I can add a plain image to this `StatusStrip` control?  Should I be using a different Windows Forms control?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add StatusLabel controls and use the Image property.

Comment: Ok, so StatusLabel isn't just a label?  Thanks for that, I'll give it a try.

Comment: No, "label" in this context is quite broad :)

Comment: +1 for that, your answer helped me 3 years later. They sure know how to make it hard to find with a name like Label.

Comment: +1 indeed, it's interesting how so many projects need old answers at the same time years after they were given

Comment: Sweet! glad to still be of some assistance guys! :)

Comment: for me as well. Windows controls aren't always intuitive!